# Any command line/text based email client on ubuntu which can access 'microsoft outlook exchange'?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there any command line/text based email client on ubuntu which can access 'Microsoft outlook exchange' emails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pine is a unix comand line utility for email and should handle it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_(email_client)

http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Pine-Exchange.html